# Spring Data Cassandra: How to query tables with compound keys?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have the following column family:

```
@Table(value = "request_event")
public class RequestEvent {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "day_requested", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private LocalDate dayRequested;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "date_requested", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING)
    private LocalDateTime dateRequested;

    ...
}
```

which is stored and accessed by a repository:

```
@Repository
public interface RequestEventRepository extends CrudRepository<RequestEvent, LocalDateTime> {
}
```

Unfortunately `requestEventRepository.findOne(localDate)` is throwing an exception, probably because it is returning multiple results. How can I fix this? Also, how can all results from a particular day be retrieved?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two options to represent compound keys with Spring Data Cassandra:

1. Using `@PrimaryKeyColumn` within the domain type (like you did).
2. Using a `@PrimaryKeyClass` to represent the primary key and embed it in the domain type.

Spring Data repositories accept a single `ID` type. Therefore it's not possible to just declare `LocalDateTime` as id. If you want to stick  to `@PrimaryKeyColumn` within the domain type, the use `MapId` as id type:

```
@Table(value = "request_event")
public class RequestEvent {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "day_requested", ordinal = 0,
            type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED) 
    private LocalDate dayRequested;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "date_requested", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED,
            ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING) 
    private LocalDateTime dateRequested;

}

public interface RequestEventRepository extends CrudRepository<RequestEvent, MapId> {}

MapId mapId = BasicMapId.id("dayRequested", …).with("dateRequested", …);

RequestEvent loaded = eventRepository.findOne(mapId);
```

If you decide to represent your primary key as a value object, then you need to adjust your domain type slightly:

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class Key implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "day_requested", ordinal = 0,
            type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED) 
    private LocalDate dayRequested;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "date_requested", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED,
            ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING) 
    private LocalDateTime dateRequested;

}

@Table(value = "request_event")
public class RequestEvent {

    @PrimaryKey 
    private Key key;

}

public interface RequestEventRepository extends CrudRepository<RequestEvent, Key> {}

eventRepository.findOne(new Key(…))
```

Comment: You need to include the property path in the query method name. For the example above it would be `findAllByKeyDayRequested(…)`.

Comment: And Spring also provides a `MapIdCassandraRepository`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to add that latest versions of spring-data-cassandra include a new Repository Interface that obviates the need of specifying the `Primary Keys` or `MapId` in the Main Repository Interface.

Use `MapIdCassandraRepository` instead of `CassandraRepository`:

```
public interface MyTableRepository extends MapIdCassandraRepository<MyTable> {
}
```

As you can see in the above code, extending `MapIdCassandraRepository` interface only requires to indicate your desired Table.

Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.migration

Answer (score 1):

Just create additional query methods in the RequestEventRepository.

```
@Repository
public interface RequestEventRepository extends CrudRepository<RequestEvent, LocalDateTime> {
    List<RequestEvent> findAllByDayRequested(LocalDateTime day);
    RequestEvent findOneByDayRequestedAndDateRequested(LocalDateTime day, LocalDateTime localDateTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search by partition key of your key class
then you need to add a new method in Respository Interface
The new method name will follow this convention

//{MethodName}{PrimaryKeyClassName}{PrimaryKeyColumn}

**EXAMPLE**:

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class UserKey implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "email", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String email;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "firstname", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING)
    private String firstName;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "lastname", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING)
    private String lastName;
    //equals and hashcode methods
}
```

Then the method name will be

```
User findByUserKeyEmail(String email);
```